# InnoSetup + MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, inno-setup

Buenas hace poco he comenzado con el InnoSetup y no consigo que se me cree el usuario que quiero por defecto en el puerto 3307. Lo he intentado de varias formas y el código en si no muestra errores pero quizás porque solo los ignora. Podriais echar un vistazo a ver si vosotros podéis encontrar el problema?
Esta es la linea del [RUN]

> Filename: msiexec.exe; Check: not
>   InstalledApplication('MariaDB','10.4'); Parameters: "/i
>   ""{tmp}\mariadb-10.4.6-winx64.msi"" SERVICENAME=G2DatabaseService
>   DATADIR=""{pf}\MariaDB\MariaDB 10.4\data"" PORT=3307
>   BUFFERPOOLSIZE=2Gb DEFAULTUSER=root PASSWORD=root
>   ALLOWREMOTEROOTACCESS=1 /passive"; WorkingDir:{app};
>   StatusMsg:"{cm:waitDatabase}" ; Flags: runhidden ;Components:
>   full;BeforeInstall: UpdateProgress(91); AfterInstall:
>   UpdateProgress(95); Tasks:MariaDB;

Se instala todo correctamente pero no me genera el usuario y la password pero si que aplica el puerto 3307 por defecto